# Why is it true that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\int^x_0e^{t^2} dt=1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Why is it true that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\int^x_0e^{t^2} dt=1$?

An answer given online that uses fundamental theorem of calculus is that let $F(x)=\int^x_0e^{t^2} dt$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\int^x_0e^{t^2} dt=F'(0)=e^0=1$. But this doesn't quite make sense to me. Where does the $\frac1x $ and the $\lim$ go?

Comment: Erm... $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}x=1.$ Where does the $\lim$ go? $\sqrt{4}=2,$where does the $\sqrt{}$ go?

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of $F$ at $0$ (that is, $F'(0)$) is
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)}{x}$$

Comment: Do you mean $F(x)=\int^x_0e^{t^2} dt$ and also $F(x)-F(0)=\int^x_0e^{t^2} dt$?

Comment: @CoolKid That's probably a yes, because $F(0)=0.$

Comment: In which theory does it say that $\int^0_0e^{t^2} dt=0$?

Comment: $\int_a^a f(t) \ dt =0$

Comment: @CoolKid This is a very basic fact of integration. In this case, since $e^{t^2}$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, we could prove it by noting $0\le\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt\le\int_0^xe^{1^2}dt=e\cdot x$ for any $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: By definition $\int_{a} ^{a} f(t) \, dt=0$ for any function $f$. You don't need any justification for it.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $F'(0) = \lim \limits_{x \longrightarrow 0} \dfrac{F(x) - F(0)}{x - 0} = \lim \limits_{x \longrightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{x} F(x)$ since $F(0) = 0$.

Also, from fundamental theorem of calculus, $\dfrac{d}{dx} \int \limits_{a}^{x} f(t)dt = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting how people look at the same problem and see different things. I see an integral with $e^{t^2}$ and think *error function*, or in this case, more appropriately *imaginary* error function. Thus I write

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\int^x_0e^{t^2} dt
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfi}(x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(-i)\text{erf}(ix) \\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}(-i)\left(ix-\frac{(ix)^3}{3}+\frac{(ix)^5}{10}+\cdots \right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x \left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{10}+\cdots \right)\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply [L'Hôpital Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) followed by [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: This seems like a bit of a hammer. Understanding differentiation and the fundamental theorem of calculus is a much better way to go.

Comment: @Jason It's always nice to know an alternate way of doing something.

Comment: Yes, but this alternative method does not require, and perhaps even obscures, understanding. L'Hopital's rule is derived from the definition of differentiation and the Leibniz rule is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus. This kind of reminds when people suggest using L'Hopital's rule to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x$ - it technically works, but if that is your go-to then it suggests you don't have a solid grasp on differentiation.